# How to consume this JSON structure via Retrofit 2?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Hello I have a json structure and I need to get the datas from url. How can I do that? What are classes and functions. Please help me. Thanks.

here is my json.

```html
{
nodes: [
{
node: {
title: "...",
field_news_image: [
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."}
],
body: "...",
field_category: "...",
created: "..."
}
},
{
node: {
title: "...",
field_news_image: [
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."},
{title="..."}
],
body: "...",
field_category: "...",
created: "..."
}
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonschema2pojo.org Paste you responce and it will generate Java classes for you.
You instantiate Retrofit instance by setting all necessary components like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

and your interfaces will look like:

```
@GET("api/service/schedule/{filial}")
    Observable<Response<List<Event>>> getSchedule(@Path("filial") String filial);
```

where @GET- annotation defining request type,
Response<> - type used by Retrofit, carrying information whether response is successful or not (see class methods).
Observable<> - type from rxJava library, allowing to process request in reactive way.
I strongly recommend to use RxJava, because it simplifies execution in background very much. (DON't use AsyncTasks!!).

in order to use Retrofit2 add following lines to your Gradle file:

```
   //Reactive programming
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.0'


    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    //retrofit and okhttp
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'
```

You will instantiate Retrofit2 interface by a similar call:
retrofit.create(Api.class)

Comment: And my retrofit interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

**http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/**

Put your JSON response here and download java code from this website . Then put this java code into your project and use it . This website will make all required classes with all required fields which will be perfect fit for your response of JSON. I have used it many time this will surely work.

**http://square.github.io/retrofit/** here you can get detailed information about how to use retrofit to POST or GET data .

Retrofit turns your HTTP API into a Java interface.

```
public interface YourService {
  @GET("users/{user}/repos")
  Call<List<Repository>> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

The Retrofit class generates an implementation of the  interface.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://api.yourAPI.com/")
    .build();

YourService  service = retrofit.create(YourService .class);

Call<List<Repository>> repos = service.listRepos("myrepository");
```

Use annotations to describe the **HTTP** request:

- URL parameter replacement and query parameter support Object
  conversion to request body (e.g., JSON, protocol buffers) Multipart
  request body and file upload