# Request with JSON body and double header entries

Tags: android, postman

I have this request on Postman :

[image: Header part]

[image: Body part]

How can i make this request on Android?

Comment: Use `retrofit` or `volley` libraries to make `http` requests

Answer (score 0):

You ca  use very convenient service jsonschematopojo.org which will create java objects feom your Rest response and retrofit library. See post [How to consume this JSON structure via Retrofit 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38002973/6175778)