# get dynamic url with json in listview

Tags: java, android, json

im new programmer in android, i write program to get image url and show the image in list view, my program work correct and can show me the images but when i want to show image i should use static url, but i want to use static link to get all image url with json and show it in list view.

i have json class to get image url but i dont know how to use it in 
private String imageUrls[] to get image dynamic url from my static link.

***string url is static link in mainactivity to get image url with json.

my mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final String url="http://192.168.1.4:81/upload/images.php";

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, imageUrls);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private String imageUrls[] = {
        "http://www.technotalkative.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/tt_listview1-171x300.png",
        "http://www.technotalkative.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/f-DayDream-Example-Landscape.png",
};


}
```

and json class:

```
class get url extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("login");
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        List<NameValuePair> parms=new ArrayList<>();
        JSONObject json=jParser.makeHTTPRequest(url,"GET");

        try {
            int t=json.getInt("t");
            if(t==1){
                s=json.getJSONArray("travel");
                for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){

                    String url_image=c.getString("url_image");

                    HashMap<String,String>map=new HashMap<String,String>();

                    map.put("url_image",url_image);

                    P.add(map);

                }
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much more convenient to use Gson library gor parsing json response to java objects instead of extracting fields manually. It is also a good practice ( more convenient) to use Retrofit library instead of asynctasks - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002999/6175778 post